# Python tkinter: Replacing an image button with an image label

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I'm trying to make a code that would replace an image button with an image label when the button is pressed. But the window isn't updating so the new image doesn't became visible. Can anybody help me? If it is even possible to do that way.

There is the code I'm trying:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

gifdir = "./"
class Game:
   def __init__(self):
      self.__window = Tk()



      igm = PhotoImage(file=gifdir+"empty.gif")

      Button(self.__window, image=igm, command= self.change_picture)\
      .grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=E)

      def change_picture():
        igm = PhotoImage(file=gifdir+"new.gif")
        Label(self.__window, image=igm,)\
        .grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=E)

       self.__window.mainloop()

def main():
    Game()


main()
```

When I add this code to the end:

```
   self.__window.update_idletasks()
   time.sleep(1)
```

the new picture is shown for a one second but I need to see it all the  time and still be able to press other buttons.

Comment: Can you provide complete code. what is 'self.' referring to?

Comment: I added more code there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code, as your code is very strangely designed, and incorrect IMO. This is the modified version:

```
from tkinter import *

import time

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__window = Tk()

        self.gifdir = "./"

        self.igm = PhotoImage(file=self.gifdir+"empty.gif")

        self.btn = Button(self.__window, image=self.igm, command = self.change_picture)
        self.btn.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=E)

        self.__window.mainloop()                

    def change_picture(self):
        self.igm = PhotoImage(file=self.gifdir+"new.gif")
        self.btn.configure(image = self.igm)              


def main():
    Game()


main()
```

In this new version, pressing the button, will change the image on it. Basically, in your class, you need to keep references to created widgets. Especially keeping a reference for `PhotoImage` is important, as if the reference is not kept, garbage collector will remove the image, when instance of `PhotoImage` will go out of scope in `change_picture`.

Comment: If you add an other button you can press only one of them. Can it be fixed?

Comment: In you edit you making second button for `self.btn`. You need to create `self.btn2` or some other variable to hold reference to the new button.

Comment: Still if you press the other button you can't anymore press the other one. And is it possible to change pressed button to label so it can't be pressed again and the new picture in the label is visible?

Comment: @ottebot please edit your question or make new one if this is a new problem than the one in the current question.

Comment: @ottebot If this answer is helpful and solves this problem, accepting it would be good.